# Text inside div won't wrap

Tags: html, css

As seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/EhnuZ/ the top group has a short amount of text, and the text is to the right of the image. The bottom group is identical except that it has more text inside. However, this causes the text to shift below the image, instead of wrapping like I want it to. How can this be solved? I have tried:

```
white-space:normal;
word-wrap: break-word;
width:50%;
max-width:50%;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a `width` for the text container, otherwise it automatically tries to be 100% of the width.

```
.text{
         vertical-align:top;
         display:inline-block;
         width: 30%;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a width on the `<p>` or one of its containing elements, there is no reason for the browser's rendering engine to prevent the element from expanding to fill its container.

What you want to do is constrain the width of the paragraph of its parent by setting a `width` or  `max-width` on it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using float:left on your image?

Comment: yes, but that causes other problems when printing or displaying in a small window.